# how to add extensions that will visible to the client only when she needs it?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, design-patterns

I have Order class:

```
public class Order : IOrder
    {
        public long Id { get; private set; }
        public string Serial { get; private set; }
        public long CustomerId { get; set; }

        public Order() { }

        public IOrderItems GetOrderItems()
        {
            return new OrderItems(Id);
        }

    }
```

And I wanted to add and extension to order: OrderItems, so I used the Extension Object Patterns - as you can see Order have GetOrderItems(). OrderItems looks like:

```
public class OrderItems : IOrderItems
{
    public IItem[] Items { get; set; }

    public OrderItems(long orderId)
    {
        Items = Item.GetItems(orderId);
    }
}
```

Since I am writing web application, I am using web services.
My problem is that sometimes I need to retrieve the Order data without its Items and somwtimes I need to retrieve the Order data with it's Items.
Retrieving Order object doesn't help much since it don't retrieve to the client it's Items. If I'll convert GetOrderItems to a property - I'll always return the OrderItems to the client which is not what I am looking for.

In addition - sometimes the client would want to call one webservice with only Order as parameter and sometimes  the client would want to call other webservice with Order and Items as parameters.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question, but can't you just provide two methods in your web service to cover both options? So if we change your `Order` class like this:

```
public class Order : IOrder 
{ 
    public long Id { get; private set; } 
    public string Serial { get; private set; } 
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
    public IOrderItems OrderItems { get; set; }

    public Order() { } 

    internal IOrderItems LoadOrderItems() 
    { 
        OrderItems = new OrderItems(Id); 
    } 
}
```

You can then add a web service implementation which would be roughly as follows:

```
public class OrdersService : IOrderService
{
    public IOrder LoadOrderOnly(long id)
    {
        var order = someDataAccessInstance.LoadOrder(id);
        return order;
    }

    public IOrder LoadOrderWithItems(long id)
    {
        var order = someDataAccessInstance.LoadOrder(id);
        order.LoadOrderItems();
        return order;
    }
}
```

Comment: This may works but what do you think about that: one may initialize order using new Order(); and then may think that OrderItems is not empty. What do you think?

Comment: Another question - what if I have webservice that return all the orders with thier items, in this case I have to loop all the orders in order to load the Items?

Comment: I am assuming there are very specific circumstances in which your client has called either one method or the other in order to get the data. If not, then the client would always need to check whether the OrderItems property is null - which it would be if LoadOrderOnly is called.

Comment: In that case, your service methods would return a collection or array, and would not need an ID, eg public IOrder[] LoadOrdersOnly()